# Is a REST messaging layer for micro services fast enough?

Tags: node.js, http, microservices

I know very little of micro services so this is part of my learning phase for sure. Say I have multiple nodejs micro services (Auth Service, User Service, Vehicles Service etc). What is the best way to share data between then?

**Are HTTP calls good enough?** Because it is very easy to just call many HTTP calls from a "Pointsman" service or something. All these nodejs services will be running on the same machine so they should have quite fast speeds. HTTP calls are also async, so you can control how service wait for each other rather easily. Basic calling tests seem super fast, but it is hard to know how bigger pieces of data will work.

The reason why I ask is because people talk about messaging layers. Where messages will lie in a place for services to watch. So services will place and pick up messages assign for them.

I just feel like HTTP calls are good enough, why not use them?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about fast enough but rather scaleable and available microservices.

**HTTP protocol is sync**

There is very wide misconception that HTTP is async. Http is synchronous protocol but your client could deal it async. E.g. when you call any service using http your http client would schedule is on the backend thread (async). However The http call will be waiting until either it's timeout or response is back , during all this time the http call chain is awaiting synchronously. Now if you have hundreds of requests at a time you can image how many http calls are scheduled synchronously and you may run of sockets.

**AMQP**

In Microservices architecture we prefer AMQP (Advance message queue protocol) . Which means the service drops the message in queue and forgets about it. This is true async transport protocol since your service is done once it drops the message in the queue and interested services will pick those.

This type of protocol is preferred since you can scale without worry even when other services are down as they will eventually get message/event/data.

That's why HTTP is not preferred way to share the messages/data.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question we need to understand that there are diff. kinds of communication that needs to happen between microservices and based on that there are diff. approaches.

Lets discussion about type of communication by taking a domain example of Facebook :

1. **FOR MESSAGING** You like on some post. In this case lots of things needs to happen like first of all count of like on post need to increase , then some recommendation service will try to see what kinds of post you like based on that change your recommendations , some app service will send some notifications to apps about the post update and so on. In these cases where based on some event like UserLikedAPost many a things needs to happen in diff. microservice we should write such event in a Message Queue like Kafka or Rabbit MQ and then other services can subscribe and do the respective work.

In this case as we do not want all the other operations to complete before sending the final response for user HTTP request as it will make the post like request time to increase.

2. **FOR HTTP OR gRPC** Get my account details: in this case while showing your data one will show your interests , your job which all are part of diff. microservice like Interest and Job. For this when one requests come that request needs to call each service either using Rest or gRPC (it is highly optimized that REST with JSON) to return the results.

Now i have given you examples that both Messaging and HTTP (or gRPC) are needed.

Also there are much more scenarios where you may prefer one over the another. You might like to read: [microservices pattern](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/microservices-when-to-react-vs-orchestrate-c6b18308a14c) to understand more about these things

Comment: I don't really agree with your Messaging example. With HTTP you can still return a async response saying `Thanks for your input. Your data is in process and we will notify you when everything is done`. So your sentence of `In this case sync will be very bad...` has nothing to do with HTTP. My point is: HTTP can still be asyncronous.

Comment: i think my example was not put correctly, my way of saying sync was: lets say UI make a HTTP request to Service 1 and Service 1 need to get data from service 2 and Service 3 to return the exact data to UI , but if say you return that your data is in progress that you need to store this state in some messaging queue or DB otherwise if that machine restarts or some error comes your message or request is lost. So if you want to return result instantaneously that one SErvice call other service using HTTP and after completion return the result. if other services needs to react then Messaging Queue

Comment: I see I see. Maybe update your answer a bit based on what you said here (this makes more sense now). Do you have any recommendations on Message Queuing tools?

Comment: Have you used RabbitMQ? If so, why is Kafka better than RabbitMQ?